# Vuetify touch support swipe element with animation effect (draggable)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, draggable, swipe

Hello I'm on a Vue project with Vuetify plugin for the styles.

I'd like to implement a swipe effect.

On the docs of vuetify there is https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/touch-support 
But it only detects the swipe direction and that's it.

I want the same that mobile apps do. Swipe dragging an element, and when you've moved the element X pixels it executes the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Vuetify doesn't have a draggable component that I am aware of, the [awesome-vue draggable section](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#drag-and-drop) can probably help you. It has a wide variety of amazing vue tools for drag and drop interfaces. Hope this helps!